# Как корректно настроить принтер?

Tags: windows, принтер

Имею принтер Canon LBP 6030W, картридж - аналог, Windows 10 H2 x64.
При попытке распечатать с принтера, получаю в произвольных местах 'ослабление оттенка' в виде полос чуть более бледного оттенка.
Подскажите как корректно настроить принтер?

Предпринятые меры:
1) перепробовал все, ну или почти все настройки печати в свойствах принтера
2) пробовал менять обработчик печати
3) печать с разных приложений: проводник, paint, paint 3D, paint.NET, adobe acrobat.

пример:
[image: Исходное фото]
[image: Результат]

Comment: Так может это механическая проблема?

Comment: Поддерживаю, скорее всего механическая проблема. Скорее всего с "нулёвым" картриджем (или с оригинальным) такой проблемы не будет.

Comment: опробовал на другом принтере, там получше, то же самое, но не так явно, а почти незаметно.

Comment: Проблема скорее всего в барабане.